# How to call super() from another class?

Tags: java, android

I have this method:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {   

    AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this).create();
    alertDialog.setCancelable(false);
    alertDialog.setTitle("Sair");
    alertDialog.setMessage("Do you wanna leave?");
    alertDialog.setButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE, "Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
          public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
              dialog.dismiss();
              super.onBackPressed();
          }                  
         });

    alertDialog.show();
}
```

This method gives me the following error:

```
The method onBackPressed() is undefined for the type Object.
```

How can I call this super method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make the function static and call it statically, or you could grab the instance of it (might need to make it a singleton) and use that.

Answer (score 3):

you need to qualify the enclosing class:  `EnclosingClass.super.onBackPressed();`  I'm not 100% sure that works for `super` but it does for `this`.